# how to read content in a webpage that doesn't appear in page source

Tags: javascript, css, parsing, html

I would like to read this web page with python

http://www.hm.com/us/subdepartment/LADIES?Nr=4294962278#Nr=4294962278&size=100

In the web page source code there are only 24 products urls (http://www.hm.com/us/product.*)

While in the webpage itself (not the source) I see more than 24 products.

How can I read all the products and not just the first 24?

It probably has something to do with the css and the parameters in the url, but I don't really know much about this and would appreciate if someone could help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rest are being loaded in by javascript, which is clientside which is why when you view the source there is nothing there but the original 24, if you disable javascript then view the page you'll see only the 1st few.

Unless there is a JS renderer for Python you might be out of luck?

Either that or call the same page that the javascript does instead

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean by : "call the same page that the javascript does instead"

Comment: the javascript in the page would request a page like /getMoreProducts/ which would load in more. So if instead of your script going to /viewProducts you might be able to go to the same url that the javascript goes to. which from a quick look it actually loads http://www.hm.com/us/subdepartment/LADIES?Nr=4294962278&size=100&xhr=true notice the xhr=true on the url maybe have a look there?

Answer (score 0):

What you could use is the Selenium WebDriver bindings for Python and get WebDriver to visit the page in question which will give you access to page programatically. This is a good into to [WebDriver with Python](http://python.dzone.com/articles/python-getting-started) and the [Documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/index.html).